# discussion in number of views and tags

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have a question about my Super User post: [SNMP : I HAVE 2 community name?](https://superuser.com/questions/1252767/snmp-i-have-2-community-name)

I post this question from three deys , and until now the views number it's just 12 views so how we can increase the number of views

and anther question  for put my one tag , I need 200 rep for put my own one, FOR example I want to put tag special to my post put I didn't find like it in the suggest, I think 200 rep it's too mach for tags

Comment: Hello Yazan: _"How to make more visible a post?"_... nice question without a definitive answer. First try to make it more interesting, try to follow the [ask] page rules, and try to correct the spelling. Add some link: you can find people interested but that do not absolutely know what zebra is (or whatever). Focus the problem and formalize it in a clear way. Show your efforts. Good luck.

Comment: I read the terms, but like what I said before I need to improve my English :(

Comment: What tag were you trying to create? We restrict the creation of tags to prevent being inundated by useless "meta" tags that do not help to clarify the problem.

Comment: like: snmp-community-name

Comment: @yazan - If that tag existed your question wouldn't be improved in the slightest.  You are getting attention by knowable members of the community.  You should use the feedback you are getting to improve your question.